# Breaking an array of users in a group of sub-arrays

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I would like to break a array with users:

```
[
    {name: "Carlos"},
    {name: "Marcos"},
    {name: "Fernando"},
    {name: "Jhon"},
    {name: "Loius"},
    {name: "Jacob"},
]
```

And get something like this:

```
[
    [
        {name: "Jhon"},
        {name: "Loius"},
        {name: "Jacob"},
    ],
    [
        {name: "Carlos"},
        {name: "Marcos"},
        {name: "Fernando"},
    ]
]
```

The criterion for splitting them is that I want that each sub array to have a maximum of 3 users, but the number of sub arrays can be unlimited.

Comment: What's the criterion for splitting them?

Comment: what's the logic?

Comment: `[ {"user"} ]` --> `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`. This is invalid JS.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: yeh; what's your game?  3 per array, or half in each of two, or just arbitrary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function splitIntoParts(input, maxElementsPerPart) {
  const inputClone = [...input]; // create a copy because splice modifies the original array reference.
  const result = [];
  const parts = Math.ceil(input.length/maxElementsPerPart);
  for(let i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
     result.push(inputClone.splice(0, maxElementsPerPart));  
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(splitIntoParts([
  {name: "Carlos"},
  {name: "Marcos"},
  {name: "Fernando"},
  {name: "Jhon"},
  {name: "Loius"},
  {name: "Jacob"},
  {name: "Simon"},
], 3));
```

Comment: That is it! Thank you Ayush Gupta

Comment: @YagoAzedias There was a couple errors in the above code, just fixed them.

Comment: Don't `splice` in a loop. that's awfully slow and most of the time unnecessary. Why don't you just `slice` the proper items for each part?

Comment: @Thomas according to https://jsperf.com/splice-vs-splice, `splice` is faster than `slice`

Comment: @AyushGupta Yes, because that benchmark is crap. with every iteration of `splice` it's shortending the array it's splicing. So this test basically shows that it is faster to `splice` 0 out of 0 items *(after like 20 iterations)*, than it is to `slice` 500000 out of 1000000 items ;) Don't believe microbenchmarks, they rarely ever benchmark what you think they do.

Answer (score 2):

`chunk` is elegantly expressed using functional style

```js
const chunk = (xs = [], n = 1) =>
  xs.length <= n
    ? [ xs ]
    : [ xs.slice (0, n) ] .concat (chunk (xs.slice (n), n))
    
const data =
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
  
console.log (chunk (data, 1))
// [ [ 1 ], [ 2 ], [ 3 ], [ 4 ], [ 5 ], [ 6 ] ]

console.log (chunk (data, 2))
// [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ] ]

console.log (chunk (data, 3))
// [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ] ]

console.log (chunk (data, 4))
// [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ] ]

console.log (chunk ())
// [ [ ] ]
```

I think `take` and `drop` abstractions make the function read a littler nicer. Your opinion may vary.

```
const take = (xs = [], n = 1) =>
  xs.slice (0, n)

const drop = (xs = [], n = 1) =>
  xs.slice (n)

const chunk = (xs = [], n = 1) =>
  xs.length <= n
    ? [ xs ]
    : [ take (xs, n) ] .concat (chunk (drop (xs, n), n))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = [
    {name: "Carlos"},
    {name: "Marcos"},
    {name: "Fernando"},
    {name: "Jhon"},
    {name: "Loius"},
    {name: "Jacob"},
]

function toGroupsOf(n, array){
  return Array.from(
    {length: Math.ceil(array.length/n)}, //how many groups
    (_,i) => array.slice(i*n, (i+1)*n)   //get the items for this group
  )
}

console.log(toGroupsOf(3, data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

or

```
function toGroupsOf(n, array){
  var groups = Array(Math.ceil(array.length/n));
  for(var i=0; i<groups.length; ++i)
    groups[i] = array.slice(i*n, (i+1)*n);
  return groups;
}
```